# Can't remount /system as rw because "read only filesystem" (SELinux problem)

Tags: root-access, 4.4-kitkat, huawei, selinux, supersu

I tried to replace Kingroot with SuperSU since in the newer versions of Kingroot you can't block all of its connections. I had some problems, SuperSU always failed to install the newer binaries, Kingroot didn't fully uninstall and sometimes I lost root.

After being unable to install SuperSU, since it always failed to install the binaries not even as a system app, I gave up and decided to keep using an old version of Kingroot (4.85). But since then, I can't write on `/system`. I tried to remount `/system` as `rw` but it always get `Mount: Read only file system`.

I tried `mount -o rw,remount /system`, `adb remount` and also through Root Explorer, Total Commander, and with `mount system RO/RW`, but none of them worked.

I think it is because SELinux mode somehow changed to enforcing while I was trying to install SuperSU. I tried with SELinuxModeChanger to change it back to permissive, but I still cant remount. I can't even uninstall Kingroot either.

What can I do? I'm using a rooted 4.4.4 Huawei phone with Kingroot, it has root but it can't write to `/system`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by unlocking the bootloader since doing a factory reset did not solve the problem of the read-only filesystem.